# Troubles reloading section with more data in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm building an app which presents departures of busses. I use a tableview to represent it, the name of the busstop is set as the section header, and each row in a section represents a departure from that busstop.

The API always provide me with the next 20 departures for each stop, but initially I just show the next 6 departures in each section, I keep all the 20 in my datasource though. At the end of each section I have a cells which is supposed to double the shown departures in each section. It's done it this way:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section) as IndexSet, with: .none)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

My initial thought was that I could just double the returnvalue of the `numberOfRowsInSection`-function for the specific section, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
var scale = [Int : Int]()

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if stops.count != nil {
        return stops.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return stops[indexPath.row].departures.count - scale[stops[section].id]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if stops != nil {
           let currentDeparture = stops[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].departures![(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
           let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! DepartureTableViewCell
            // Configuration of the cell
            return cell
            }
        }
    return UITableViewCell()           
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.row == (stops[indexPath.row].departures.count)!   {
        var currentScale = scale[stops[indexPath.section].id]
        scale[stops[indexPath.section].id] = currentScale - 6
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: indexPath.section) as IndexSet, with: .none)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        }
   }
```

The dictionary `scale` is just mapping the ID of the stop to the number of departures that should be shown, starting at 14 (20-6) and each time the cell that is supposed to reload the section is tapped, it get reduced by 6. So we get 6 more departures in the given section. `currentDepartureresInSection` is the number of departures at the specific stop.

It is possible to do it this way, or do I have to update the datasource of the tableview?

Comment: "_My initial thought was that I could just double the returnvalue of the numberOfRowsInSection_" I smell something wrong there! Are you returning a static value in your `numberOfRows`? Please show your code.

Comment: No static value. I have added the code above.

Comment: You need to add more of your code. We don't know what `currentDepaturesInSection` or `scale` is.

Comment: The two is briefly explained below the code, do you need more? It all works perfectly, except when I try  to present more departures by increasing numberOfRowsInSection and use tableview.reloadSections. The scale variable depends on the section it is called from.

Comment: If you whole class is not too big. I recommend you share it, because there are a lot of places where the problem can occur. But mainly where you change your data source.

Comment: As mentioned above, I don't change the datasource, the datasource is done after fetching data from the API. I'm just representing a part of the datasource initially, and select a larger part when the sections is reloaded.

Comment: Please share your whole code. Thanks. I can only make assumptions from here on what might have gone wrong in your code. :)

Comment: The class is massive so I have to cherrypick a bit. I'll paste the code as soon as possible, and thanks for your attention!

Comment: How about all the tableView delegates for a start? and the place where you are updating the section?

Comment: Did you try calling the reloadData() method on the table view after changing the value of scale?

Comment: The whole idea of using reloadSections is to not reload the entire tableview, but only the section.

Comment: Unrelated but `begin-/endUpdates()` before and after a `reload` line is completely useless. It has no effect at all.